# Formatting errors - issues with code formation

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, parse-platform

I have experienced various minor errors with forming my code, and is having difficulty resolving them.
In particular,  I have the following line underline with the following message

```
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
The method findInBackground(FindCallback<ParseUser>) in the type ParseQuery<ParseUser> is not applicable for the arguments (new FindCallback<ParseObject>(){})
```

As well as errors closing my statements.
[image]

and finally
[image]

Below is the complete code

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Update:

[image]

Updated code

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public interface Constants {
        String LOG = "com.dooba.beta";
    }

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ArrayList<String> age;
    private ArrayList<String> headline;
    private ArrayList<String> activityname;

    private ArrayList<Images> alProfilePicture;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber(
            "Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString(
            "Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container,
                false);

        return view;
    }

    private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        age = new ArrayList<String>();
        headline = new ArrayList<String>();
        activityname = new ArrayList<String>();

        alProfilePicture = new ArrayList<Images>();

        // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query.setLimit(1);
        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        query.orderByDescending("Name");

        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "");

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryo = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");

        queryo.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        queryo.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        queryo.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        queryo.setLimit(1);
        queryo.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        queryo.orderByDescending("Name");


        queryo.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {


            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> object, ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ParseFile image = object.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");

                ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) getView()
                        .findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);

                // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to
                // be replaced by the fetched image
                // data.
                imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.profile_pict));
                imageView.setParseFile(image);
                imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                        Log.i("ParseImageView",
                                "Fetched! Data length: " + data.length
                                        + ", or exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }};

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistname, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistname.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userlistname.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistname);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            names);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            public void done1(List<ParseUser> userlistheadline, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistheadline.size(); i++) {
                        headline.add(userlistheadline.get(i).get("Headline")
                                .toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistheadline);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_all,
                            headline);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            public void done2(List<ParseUser> userlistage, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistage.size(); i++) {
                        age.add(userlistage.get(i).get("Age").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistage);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            age);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            public void done3(List<ParseUser> userlistactivity, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistactivity.size(); i++) {
                        activityname.add(userlistactivity.get(i)
                                .get("ActivityName").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistactivityname);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            activityname);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error finding that user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Update 2
a few formating issues such as
[image]
1) object cannot be resolved

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public interface Constants {
        String LOG = "com.dooba.beta";
    }

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ArrayList<String> age;
    private ArrayList<String> headline;
    private ArrayList<String> activityname;

    private ArrayList<Images> alProfilePicture;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber(
            "Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString(
            "Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container,
                false);

        return view;
    }

    private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        age = new ArrayList<String>();
        headline = new ArrayList<String>();
        activityname = new ArrayList<String>();

        alProfilePicture = new ArrayList<Images>();

        // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query.setLimit(1);
        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        query.orderByDescending("Name");

        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "");




        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> users,ParseException e) {

                // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");

                ParseFile image = object.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");


                ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);

                 // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to be replaced by the fetched image
                 // data.
                 imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_pict));
                 imageView.setParseFile(image);
                 imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                     Log.i("ParseImageView",
                         "Fetched! Data length: " + data.length + ", or exception: " + e.getMessage());
                   }


             });
            }
        });

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistname, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistname.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userlistname.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistname);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            names);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
                }
            });

        }
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistheadline, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistheadline.size(); i++) {
                        headline.add(userlistheadline.get(i).get("Headline")
                                .toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistheadline);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_all,
                            headline);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done2(List<ParseUser> userlistage, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistage.size(); i++) {
                        age.add(userlistage.get(i).get("Age").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistage);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            age);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done3(List<ParseUser> userlistactivity, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistactivity.size(); i++) {
                        activityname.add(userlistactivity.get(i)
                                .get("ActivityName").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistactivityname);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            activityname);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error finding that user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: just remove }); in each line you get the message. After that type in Ctrl+Shift+F

Comment: And it seems to be `new FindCallback<ParseUser>()` instead of `new FindCallback<ParseObject>()`.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. Any idea on how I solve the following: The method findInBackground(FindCallback<ParseUser>) in the type ParseQuery<ParseUser> is not applicable for the arguments (new FindCallback<ParseObject>(){}) ?

Comment: When i switch it to new FindCallback<ParseUser>() I recieve the following error: The type new FindCallback<ParseUser>(){} must implement the inherited abstract method FindCallback<ParseUser>.done(List<ParseUser>, ParseException)

Comment: I made some adjustements and believe to have resolve the issue with FindCallback<ParseUser>(), but have encountered other typo along the way. I have kindly attach a new picture and an update code under the update section of my initial post

Answer (score 1):

This should be a start:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment
{

    public interface Constants
    {
        String LOG = "com.dooba.beta";
    }

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ArrayList<String> age;
    private ArrayList<String> headline;
    private ArrayList<String> activityname;

    private ArrayList<Images> alProfilePicture;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
            .getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
            .getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
            .getNumber("Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
            .getString("Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
            .getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
            .getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
            .getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container,
                false);

        return view;
    }

    private void setConversationsList()
    {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        age = new ArrayList<String>();
        headline = new ArrayList<String>();
        activityname = new ArrayList<String>();

        alProfilePicture = new ArrayList<Images>();

        // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query.setLimit(1);
        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        query.orderByDescending("Name");

        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "");

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryo = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");

        queryo.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        queryo.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        queryo.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        queryo.setLimit(1);
        queryo.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        queryo.orderByDescending("Name");


        queryo.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>()
        {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> object, ParseException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ParseFile image = object.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");

                ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) getView()
                        .findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);

                // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to
                // be replaced by the fetched image
                // data.
                imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.profile_pict));
                imageView.setParseFile(image);
                imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e)
                    {
                        Log.i("ParseImageView",
                                "Fetched! Data length: " + data.length
                                        + ", or exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }

            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>()
            {

                public void done (List < ParseUser > userlistname, ParseException e)
                {
                    if(e == null)
                    {
                        for(int i = 0; i < userlistname.size(); i++)
                        {
                            names.add(userlistname.get(i)
                                    .get("Name")
                                    .toString());
                        }
                        usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                                R.id.userlistname);
                        namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                                .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                                names);
                        usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                        usersListView
                                .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                            View v, int i, long l)
                                    {
                                        openConversation(names, i);
                                    }
                                });

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                }
            });

            public void done1(List<ParseUser> userlistheadline, ParseException e)
            {
                if(e == null)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < userlistheadline.size(); i++)
                    {
                        headline.add(userlistheadline.get(i)
                                .get("Headline")
                                .toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistheadline);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_all,
                            headline);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                        View v, int i, long l)
                                {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            public void done2(List<ParseUser> userlistage, ParseException e)
            {
                if(e == null)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < userlistage.size(); i++)
                    {
                        age.add(userlistage.get(i)
                                .get("Age")
                                .toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistage);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            age);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                        View v, int i, long l)
                                {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

            public void done3(List<ParseUser> userlistactivity, ParseException e)
            {
                if(e == null)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < userlistactivity.size(); i++)
                    {
                        activityname.add(userlistactivity.get(i)
                                .get("ActivityName")
                                .toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistactivityname);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            activityname);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                        View v, int i, long l)
                                {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos)
    {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>()
        {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e)
            {
                if(e == null)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0)
                            .getObjectId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error finding that user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response. It has helped resolved much issue, however, I have an issue with the following line:                 ParseFile image = object.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");
 The method getParseFile(String) is undefined for the type List<ParseObject>

Comment: Hi, I have made great progress, but is experiencing issues with the object error and a few formating issues. I have uploaded my updated code under the update section of my inital post

Comment: You should really just use your IDE to auto-format things for you, and make sure that you close the brackets where you want to close the brackets. I know the `});` is confusing, but it saves you a lot of effort if you make sure you obey the syntax of the language.